# Network up and down usage indicator

Tags: networking, indicator, applet

Is there an applet that shows an indicator on the top bar that shows the network up and down usage in kb/mb (not %)

I have come across "indicator-network" but apparently it has device issues?

Anyway im sure there's a simple applet for this.

Im using 11.10

cheers

Comment: Have you looked at conky ?

Answer (score 2):

[Netspeed Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/89889/46531) could help you. And [System Load Indicator](https://askubuntu.com/a/40019/46531) shows it as graph, and by clicking this you can read it as value. Not least you could [customize `indicator-sysmonitor`](https://askubuntu.com/a/104883/46531).