# Is an Internet connectivity indicator applet available for the Unity panel?

Tags: unity, indicator, connection

Because my internet connection is very unstable at the moment, I'd like to use a small indicator applet for the Unity panel.

Since I'm connected through a WLAN/Wifi Router, I can see in the network-applet when the connection to the router is lost, but not when the router loses the connection to the Internet.

A Windows 7 computer of mine has this functionality. It shows a black exclamation mark on yellow ground if it can't "ping" a remote server.

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 "Oneiric Ocelot" 64-Bit with Unity 3D.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Whilst you mentioned you wish to do this in the network applet - I don't think you can do this.  Here is an alternative.

**internet up**

[image]

**internet down**

[image]

**how to for 11.10 & 12.04**

It requires an indicator from a PPA together with a custom ping test script:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexeftimie/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
mkdir -p ~/scripts && cd ~/scripts
```

using:

```
gedit pingtest.sh
```

Copy and paste the code below into the new file and save & close.

Give the file execute permission:

```
chmod +x pingtest.sh
```

Start the indicator

```
indicator-sysmonitor &
```

Then in the indicator-preferences:

[image]

click "use this command" and copy and paste the following text:

```
$HOME/scripts/pingtest.sh
```

**code**

```
#!/bin/bash

if ping -c 1 -W 2 google.com > /dev/null; then
 echo "Up"
else
 echo "Down"
fi
```

Comment: This could be easily modified for Website Monitoring, wish i could +2!

Comment: @fossfreedom, 1. What application did you use to draw those arrows on the images? 2. Does it still work on 14.04? `indicator-sysmonitor` isn't available in that PPA!

Comment: @Kin - that is with Shutter!  I've created another answer for 14.04.  Hope that helps you.

Comment: @mini any news? just tried and it is not available to ubuntu trusty.. I will I will try the old deb

Comment: @mini ok, I downloaded the latest version manually from ppa and installed it with `gdebi indicator-sysmonitor_0.4.3_all.deb` (required `sudo apt-get install python-psutil` btw), it is running :)

Comment: @AquariusPower - v0.5 is available from the PPA for both Trusty and Utopic - https://launchpad.net/~fossfreedom/+archive/ubuntu/indicator-sysmonitor?field.series_filter=trusty

Comment: @fossfreedom do you think it could be used in someway to create a workaround for [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/550154/how-to-have-a-clock-indicator-highly-visible)? May be it could have custom icon/image support added?

Answer (score 19):

The [original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/104883/14356) was written for Ubuntu 11.10 & 12.04.

Since then, the indicator interface was changed for 12.10 & 13.04.  However, the [maintainer](https://launchpad.net/~alexeftimie/+archive/ppa) has not released a version since then for later Ubuntu versions.  No code commits in the launchpad PPA has been made since first quarter 2013.

Thus I have [forked the project](https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor), fixed a few bugs and made it available for 14.04 Trusty users.  Feel free to check out the code on GitHub and help out with the maintenance.

**internet up**

[image]

**internet down**

[image]

**how to for 14.04**

It requires an indicator from my PPA together with a custom ping test script:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
mkdir -p ~/scripts && cd ~/scripts
```

using:

```
gedit pingtest.sh
```

Copy and paste the code below into the new file and save & close.

Give the file execute permission:

```
chmod +x pingtest.sh
```

Start the indicator

```
indicator-sysmonitor &
```

Then in the indicator-preferences click New:

[image]

Then enter the details as shown:

[image]

i.e. use the command

```
$HOME/scripts/pingtest.sh
```

Click OK, followed by the following actions 1,2,3 & 4:

[image]
**code**

```
#!/bin/bash

if ping -c 1 -W 2 google.com > /dev/null; then
 echo "Up"
else
 echo "Down"
fi
```

Comment: I've been using [Manjaro](http://manjaro.org/) since a while now, so I can't test the solution, but I'm sure it works ;) Thanks!

Comment: after typing "indicator-sysmonitor &" I get: [1] 3660
username@host:~$ INFO:root:start
INFO:root:Menu shown
INFO:root:Fetcher started
 [1] 3660


mikeal@MITO2:~$ INFO:root:start
INFO:root:Menu shown
INFO:root:Fetcher started - no GUI is launched.

Comment: @KalamalkaKid - please raise this on the project issues page - link in the answer