# NVIDIA graphics card memory usage applet / application?

Tags: nvidia, graphics, applet

I am looking for an application to display in real-time the memory usage of my NVIDIA graphics card. Ideally I would like to have something similar to the little applet graph you can get through the System Monitor applet in GNOME.

Anybody knows if such application exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I haven't seen an applet but you can run the following in the terminal window:

```
nvidia-smi
```

Perhaps this will help you search for the exact thing you're looking for.

I did find this http://www.matrix44.net/blog/?p=876 but not sure what desktop you are using

If you are using gnome 3 then you might want to hack this https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/82/cpu-temperature-indicator/ to use nvidia-smi information instead (see comments at the bottom of that page - people discussing nvidia-smi)

Comment: Thanks mate, the script available in your first link did the trick. I had to hack it a but though. Cheers!

Comment: No worries ... I'm currently trying to hack together a gnome 3 extension to intergate this tightly.  I'll post a link if I manage to get it working

Answer (score 0):

nvidia-settings show the used memory as well

Answer (score 0):

If `nvidia-smi` and/or `nvidia-settings` are terminal commands which give the information you need, perhaps take the next step and write a script which calls those commands and gives you the output you want as text.

Then install `indicator-sysmonitor` from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/453975/67335) and add your script to `indicator-sysmonitor` as one of the sensors (and ditch the other sensors).

Comment: I have since added background script functionality to https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335 which would allow you to call 'nvidia-smi' and display the parsed/sanitised result in the panel.