# Internet Connectivity Indicator on Unity

Tags: unity, indicator, network-monitoring

How can I check whether my internet connection is active on Ubuntu. If I am connected to a wired or wi-fi network, the indicator applet shows that I'm connected. But there is now way to find out the internet is working or not. I have some problem in my internet connectivity and I frequently lose my connection. I found this link is useful

[Is an Internet connectivity indicator applet available for the Unity panel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100306/internet-connectivity-indicator-applet?lq=1)

But I don't know that where should I use this code!

```
#!/bin/bash

if ping -c 1 -W 2 google.com > /dev/null; then
 echo "Up"
else
 echo "Down"
fi
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The link you indicated is self explanatory. Even so, the necessary parts for implementing the script are:

1. Open up a console and type:

   mkdir -p ~/scripts && cd ~/scripts
2. After that type the following

   gedit pingtest.sh
3. Paste this code:

> ```
> #!/bin/bash
>
> if ping -c 1 -W 2 google.com > /dev/null; then
>  echo "Up"
> else
>  echo "Down"
> fi
> ```

1. Save the file
2. Again on the console

> chmod +x pingtest.sh

Then you have the file created, all you need is to follow the other steps indicated on the link you posted

Comment: Heres some extra info on bash for beginners https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Beginners/BashScripting