# I want to create an indicator for "LXDE Panel"

Tags: indicator, lxde

I want to create an indicator for `LXDE Panel` that prints my `GPU` temperature by using the following command:

```
watch -n 5 nvidia-smi --query-gpu = temperature.gpu --format = csv, noheader
```

I just want that mini application prints that number every 5 seconds or 2. What tools do I need to create it? How I can start? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I think that `indicator-sysmonitor` will work under LXDE.  If so, you could install it and then write a custom script which performs the GPU temperature lookup.

The gist of installing the indicator and writing a custom script are [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/501056/67335).