# Is it possible to update the app indicator from code?

Tags: unity, application-development, indicator, gtk, ruby

I use [ruby-libappindicator](https://github.com/denysonique/ruby-libappindicator) bindings to manage [ubuntu application indicators](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/).

I want to indicate if port 3000 is used by any application. Port checking isn't a problem but I also need to update the indicator (I want to show the green or red circle) when port becomes busy/free.

I can create a new indicator like this:

```
require "ruby-libappindicator"
indicator = AppIndicator::AppIndicator.new("test", "indicator-messages", AppIndicator::Category::APPLICATION_STATUS)
indicator.set_menu(Gtk::Menu.new)
indicator.set_status(AppIndicator::Status::ACTIVE)
Gtk.main
```

But after `Gtk.main` call the code "hangs" so I can't call any other method.

How I can update the appindicator icon after its creation?

Comment: It doesn't hang, Gtk.main enters the Gtk event loop, which blocks waiting for some event (system or user) to respond to.

Answer (score 1):

Use [g_timeout_add_seconds() from GLib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds) to define a function that is called at regular intervals and in this function check the port and call `indicator.set_status(...)` is needed.

Answer (score 0):

To save you writing your own indicator...

...you could install [indicator-sysmonitor](https://askubuntu.com/a/453975/67335), then create a shell script to monitor the port and add your script to the indicator.

Rather than a red/green icon, you'd have to settle for a text label to indicate state.

Comment: I have added background script functionality to https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335 which would allow you check your port and display the result in the panel (still cannot change the icon though).

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a timer using `GLib::Timeout.add_seconds`, (or just `add` if you want to use milliseconds)

```
# ...

GLib::Timeout.add_seconds(2) do # every two seconds....
    app_indicator.set_icon '/path/to/icon.svg'
    true # returning false cancels the timer
end

Gtk.main
```