# How can I get System Monitor Indicator to display temperature?

Tags: unity, 13.10, indicator, temperature, sensors

System Monitor Indicator comes with options to display CPU load, memory usage, and other system stats, but currently does not include an option to display temperature (of the CPU, HDD, SSD, GPU, etc.).

[image]

There seems to be functionality built in for adding additional sensors by applying a command (by clicking "New"). However, I don't know how, and I cannot find any documentation that describes this feature.

My system is set up to report temperature as so:

```
user@host:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +27.8°C  (crit = +106.0°C)
temp2:        +29.8°C  (crit = +106.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +79.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 0:         +79.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 1:         +77.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)

pkg-temp-0-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +79.0°C
```

This question refers to the package indicator-sysmonitor version 0.4.3 from 13.04 raring, although currently I am running it on a 13.10 saucy installation as it has not yet been updated in the ppa:

https://launchpad.net/indicator-sysmonitor

Comment: you can either wait for the indicator-sysmonitor or compile it from the source on launchpad.

Comment: I don't understand this comment. How would compiling the application myself add functionality to show temperature?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`System Monitor Indicator` is quite simple / flexible. You can add basically any script as custom sensor. The output it produces will then appear where you put its placeholder. I am using this to extract information from the output of `sensors` like this:

```
sensors | grep temp1 | awk '{print $2}' | sed 's/+//'
```

to exctract the temperature or

```
sensors | grep fan1 | awk '{print $2}'
```

to extract the fan speed.

Just click on `New`, enter a name and a description and the respective lines from above under `Command` as shown here:

[image]

PS: After upgrading from Ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 the tool seemed to have problems to read the configuration file, resulting in a crash when I tried to add sensors. Removing `.indicator-sysmonitor.json` from my home directory fixed this.

Comment: Nice - I used `sensors | grep "Core 1" | awk '{print $3}'` as it can work differently on different hardware.

Comment: how does this works on "System Load Indicator" 0.4 ; I can't see a add menu with a command enter field.

Comment: System Load Indicator is a different application. This question is about https://github.com/fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor

Comment: System monitor indicator is an awesome tool.

Answer (score 1):

There's an indicator for the temperature in this ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:alexmurray/indicator-sensors
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sensors
```

It’s already updated with packages for saucy, although I haven't tried it myself since I'm  still using 13.04.
You can then launch it from the dash or from the command-line and configure to show different sensors and set up alarms.

Comment: Thanks. I can recommend this indicator to anybody who's interested in temperature monitoring (in 13.10). However, I am still interested in answers to how to get temperature support in indicator-sysmonitor as well.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps look at what `indicator-sensors` does to get temperature information and put that into a shell script.

Then install [indicator-sysmonitor](https://askubuntu.com/a/453975/67335) and add your script to that.

Answer (score 0):

As said [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1123098/349837) you have:

#### [**system-monitor**](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/120/system-monitor/) GNOME Shell extension

[image: screenshot]

#### [**psensor**](https://askubuntu.com/a/432902/349837)

[image: screenshot]

```
sudo apt install psensor
```

Answer (score -2):

as of now  System Monitor Indicator can't show cpu temperature. Here is the answer from the author https://answers.launchpad.net/indicator-sysmonitor/+question/238748

Comment: There is no answer given at the link you provided, as far as I can see?

Comment: you right, but it was there yesterday. searching through the site, i belive it still does not support such feature now.