# How to configure sensord deamon?

Tags: temperature

I would like to configure sensord daemon to raise beep alarm if some temperature are too high.

I cannot find any guide/example, the man page is not very useful, any hint ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Temperature Warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/432895/temperature-warnings)

Answer (score 1):

Can you not use psensor? Install and configure lm-sensors, then install psensor from the software center. It will let you set alarms on any sensor it can find.

Comment: It looks fine as well, but a deamon would be better as it is less resource consuming

Comment: In addition to psensor (UI), there is also psensor-server which has an option (--sensor-log-file) to log temperatures. It consumes far more less resources than psensor (UI), but certainly more than sensors because its main purpose is to provide a web service and it does not offer any way to emit a "beep". I agree with the op, he should better use sensord.