# Is there a sample project of an indicator which makes a call to a remote service in 13.10?

Tags: indicator

I'd like to look into making an indicator for 13.10 which keeps me up to date by pulling from data on a remote service, and, if possible, in future, allows me to interact with it, e.g. trigger a build, move to the next track playing etc.

While there seems to be a fair bit of documentation regarding indicators

http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/

an example that works out of the box, that I could play around with, would be the perfect start.

Can anybody point me to either a sample project that I can install or, failing that, the source of an indicator they feel is well built and happens to grab some data remotely? Ideally this indicator would be written in Python or C#.

Even better, is there a list of official indicators (by official I mean in the Ubuntu repos as oppose to a PPA) that I could look at? If so are indicators packaged separately and thus is there a way for me to look at the source of all my installed indicators or do they typically come packaged with their application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest a two step process...

1) Install [indicator-sysmonitor](https://askubuntu.com/a/453975/67335) and then write a shell script to call the remote service and display your data (the indicator will only display though).

2) Any of the indicators listed in [What Application Indicators are available?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/30334/what-application-indicators-are-available) will give you an example of how to write indicators...that's how I learnt.

FWIW, take a look at any of my [indicators](https://launchpad.net/~thebernmeister/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) and use those as an example.  An indicator's menu comprises either static text labels (your display) or clickable menu items (which can trigger actions/scripts).