# Change the order of applet data and time numbers

Tags: applet

Is there a way to separate date from time in some way? Or maybe make day number before month.I am now using 14.04 LTS, but on 13.10 I think it was kind of separately, because now as you can see it's often confusing, at first glance it looks like it's now 19:00, while it's 00:49. On unity tweak tool I didn't find such option.

[image: Picture]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a way to alter the display of the date/time applet to how you want, so here's my alternative solution.

Install [indicator-sysmonitor](https://askubuntu.com/a/453975/67335), then create a custom shell script which will emit the date/time according to your preferred format.

Decide on what you want the date/time indicator to show (from your screenshot, I assume just the time) and then your script, via `indicator-sysmonitor`, would display the date.

The downside is the date may not be adjacent to the time...