# Light alternative for Unity clock applet (netbook)?

Tags: unity, indicator, ram, evolution, clock

Default clock applet is heavy based on `evolution` ( I think it is provided by this package )`indicator-datetime`.

For this reason, on on Ubu 14.04, it is sucking about 30mb of ram ( as for `htop` info ) that is bit too much for a clock.

[image]

Is there any other alternative ? ( I just need a clock applet that display on the upper bar )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of a simple/lean clock indicator, however I have a cunning alternative.

1) Write a shell script which gets the current date/time.

2) Install `indicator-sysmonitor` from [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/453975/67335).

3) Add your shell script to `indicator-sysmonitor` as one of the sensors (and ditch the other sensors).

4) Set the update period to be one minute, more or less frequent as needed.

I have `indicator-sysmonitor` running showing cpu/mem, updating every five seconds and uses only 15 MB.

Comment: great I didn't know `indicator-sysmonitor` look a nice util.
In the meanwhile I migrated to crunchbang, it is for sure a better( one of the best) alternative for netbook

Comment: custom text indicators, very good!

Answer (score 2):

I've used this method successfully as a workaround to Ubuntu 14.04 Bug #1317288 (clock disappears from Unity panel).

I followed the instructions from the [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100306/is-an-internet-connectivity-indicator-applet-available-for-the-unity-panel/453975#453975) above, reposted here with my bash script.

From a terminal, install indicator-sysmonitor:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:fossfreedom/indicator-sysmonitor
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install indicator-sysmonitor
```

Start the indicator

```
indicator-sysmonitor &
```

You should now see a cpu and memory indicator in your dash panel.

[image]

Click anywhere on the indicator to open its menu, and select "Preferences".  In the "General" tab, enable "Run on startup:"

[image]

Go to the "Advanced" tab and click "New".

[image]

Name your new sensor "clock", give it a description, and type the following code into the "Command" field.

```
 date +%a\ %b\ %d\ %r
```

Click "OK"

[image]

On the "Advanced" tab, in the "Customize output:" field, delete *cpu:{cpu} mem:{mem}* and type

```
{clock}
```

Change the update interval to 1.0, and click "Save".

[image]

You should now have a day + date + time indicator in your Unity dash panel.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edit Stormvirux.  Embedded images make much more sense.