# How to monitor network speed of remote system on unity panel?

Tags: unity, networking, indicator

I have a linux-based dd-wrt router that connects my home network with outside world.

I'd like to see, what is the current network load on the router in a convenience of the tray (a.k.a. indicator panel) icon.

I believe that writing such a monitoring tool is relatively easy, and I hope I don't have to write such tool myself.

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to connect to your router via a terminal and get the speed from it?  Alternatively, can the router run a script itself and so give the speed?

If so, you could then take that script and add it to [indicator-sysmonitor](https://askubuntu.com/a/453975/67335).

Comment: Oh, that is a good idea. I'll try that and when I'm ready I'll post the script.

Comment: If you are happy with this answer, please mark it as accepted - thanks.

Comment: For me it is more like a comment. There is still >5h work in research and coding to make an answer, and I am still not sure whether it will really be a feasible solution. And I'll need to properly address some difficult  corner cases to make it reliable; like handling the network timeouts.

Comment: I've since released Indicator Script Runner with background script functionality, https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335, in which you could add your script to obtain network speed display the result in the panel.