# Looking for a light weight website monitoring tool

Tags: networking, command-line, software-recommendation, indicator

I am looking for a tool that can help me monitor the availability of my website.

Basically, I should input my website URL to the tool and it should monitor whether the site is up and send the feedback to my email. It should equally hang on the status menu (indicators).

I have done some research. I came across monitorix,nagios,... but they all are not that light.

Does such a tool exists, if so can I have their links?

Comment: Do you want/need me to write a script or you giving it ago?

Comment: don't bother I would do it myself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a very basic ping test to check availability could you not write a very simple PHP/Bash program to monitor such things?

You could either ping in bash or use a method like [the one describe in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841635/how-to-ping-a-server-port-with-php) for PHP. If it successfully pings / connects to the host send an email ([Send emails with PHP](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer)) or write a log text file.

I find writing my own scripts for certain small tasks (don't re-invent the wheel) helps make me a better programmer & gives the exact output I want (instead of bending to somebody else's way), I will follow this up with a PHP script if required, but just throwing an idea out there!

Answer (score 1):

[Smokeping](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping/) is realtivly easy to setup tool which can monitor and send email alarms.

[image]

Here is a [demo](http://oss.oetiker.ch/smokeping-demo/?target=Customers.OP) of its web-interface.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a lot with newrelic lite.  You can do a lot more with a paid subscription but lite is amazing for free.

[www.newrelic.com](http://www.newrelic.com)

This isn't just an access based reporting tool like you asked for.  It's installed on the server and reports a lot of metrics about the system, even application performance monitoring. Slow scripts, MySQL execution time, etc.

Comment: If they find nagios too much, I wonder what they'll think of this.

Comment: Agreed, @muru, but you can simply add the repo, and install it and the it's reporting.  So although it can do a lot there isn't any configuration needed for simple monitoring.

Answer (score -1):

If you write a small script to ping your website and then add that script to [indicator-sysmonitor](https://askubuntu.com/a/453975/67335).

Comment: I have since added background script functionality to https://askubuntu.com/a/786708/67335.  You could write a script which pings or check for your site's availability and display the result in the indicator panel (along with emailing you).